# Smoking just after a workout

Tags: exercise, smoking, nicotine

I smoke a cigarette just after workout at gym. Can that be more dangerous than smoking at a more ordinary time? For example, can it cause sudden cardiac arrest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Smoking in general is unhealthy.  Smoking can result in emphysema, COPD, pulmonary hypertension and other ugly diseases [1,2,3].  After a workout your heart and respiration rates are higher than at basal levels.  Although I do not have data to back me on this, based on scientific evidence on cardiopulmonary effects [4] after a workout and the hazards of smoking [1,2,3], I would deduce you would have higher nicotine intake, as well as other terrible chemicals that are in cigarettes.  I am not sure if cardiac arrest would be a primary concern with smoking but rather a secondary event to pulmonary hypertension [2,3]. In short I would seek advice and support on quitting smoking.

---

1. [Smoking and Mortality — Beyond Established Causes](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMsa1407211)
2. [Severe Pulmonary Hypertension and Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease](http://www.atsjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1164/rccm.200401-006OC#.VntWDXUrKfg)
3. [Pulmonary Hypertension and Right Heart Failure in Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease](http://www.atsjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1513/pats.200407-037MS)
4. [Cardiopulmonary Exercise Testing - The Clinical Value of Gas Exchange Data](http://archinte.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=610608)